# How to Return TreeMap specific objects with Enum

Tags: java, enums

I have TreeMap with my own class as a key and Integer as a value. I have Enum class with colours. Black, White, Green, Red, Yellow, Blue. I made my method in Enum with all colours except Black and White. In main I created 6 objects TreeMap and I need to print with "for" method objects from TreeMap only with colours, that I put in Enum method, so all objects with Red, Yellow, Green, Blue. How can I do it? Thank you. Here is my code.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKuOm.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vefh.png)

Need the output:

Plains{color=RED, model='Boing', year=2020}

Plains{color=GREEN, model='Boing', year=2020}

Plains{color=BLUE, model='Boing', year=2020}

Plains{color=YELLOW, model='Boing', year=2020}

Comment: Please add your code as a text edit to the question. We try to avoid image links because they can disappear and are harder to read properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to use the Colors in the method in your enum, then just have an if statement that skips over unless they are in the 4 colors

```java
if (List.of(Color.getColorfulColors()).contains(yourObject.getColor()))
{

    System.out.println(yourObject);

}
```

Put the array in a list, call the contains method on the color of your object, and if it passes, print it out using the toString you already gave.